# Bootstrap menu not working for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used nav walker for the wordpress menu with bootstrap. but this responsive menu is not working properly when I resize the window, the toggle button shows, but not function properly.. I created it with the help of an online tutorial. the site is:
http://www.btmtesting.com/
& the code I'm using is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                      <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                      </div>                       
                      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                            <?php
                            wp_nav_menu( array(
                                'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                                'depth' => 2,
                                'container' => false,
                                'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                                'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
                                //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
                                'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                            );
                            ?>
                        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
                    </nav>
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: can you describe your issue please?

Comment: when I resize the screen the toggle button shows, but not working. I mean nothing happens when you click it. the menu items should toggle down by clicking that button.
(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Js` in this folder. Please upload `bootstrap.min.js` to this folder.

http://www.btmtesting.com/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: yes you are right. I added the js to the file, but forgot to link it properly when converting html to wordpress. actually I'm new in this line. I forgot to add it: <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `container`, and `container_class`

Please try this code, it's working for me.

**PHP Code**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">title site</a>
        </div>


        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'top-menu', //your name
                'theme_location'    => 'header-menu',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse target',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );


?>
</nav>
```

**Add this code in function.php**

```
function register_my_menus()
{
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'top-menu' => 'My Top Menu'
    ));
}
add_action('init','register_my_menus');
require_once('functions/libs/wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');
```

and this is my [website](http://wmsdardar.com/demo/thetwins/)